# Sorting ObservableCollection by nullable class property and ThenBy

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable, observablecollection

I am trying to sort an ObservabkeCollection object containing the following class

```
 public Favourites(string title=null, string uri=null, string folder=null, bool delete=false)
 {
    this.pageTitle = title;
    this.pageURI = uri;
    this.folder = folder;
    this.deleteEnabled = delete;
  }
```

I am trying to sort by folder then by uri. While the uri and title can be null, in my case I always assign them with something not null. However the folder property can be null.

My code to sort

```
    private void sortCollectionFolderFirst()
    {
        IEnumerable<Favourites> sort;
        ObservableCollection<Favourites> tempSortedFavourites = new ObservableCollection<Favourites>();
        tempFavs.Clear();
        tempFavs = settings.FavouritesSetting;

        sort = tempFavs.OrderByDescending(item => item.Folder).ThenBy(item => item.PageURI);

        foreach (var item in sort)
        {
            tempSortedFavourites.Add(item);
        }

        settings.FavouritesSetting = tempSortedFavourites;            
    }
```

The sorting is fine when the class item is

```
this.pageTitle = sometitle;
this.pageURI = someuri;
this.folder = null;
this.deleteEnabled = false or true;
```

But `sort` returns empty when it encounters an item with the following content

```
this.pageTitle = sometitle;
this.pageURI = someuri;
this.folder = somefoldername;
this.deleteEnabled = false or true;
```

Why is that?

Comment: It may be a type, but your instance members have a different case than what you are using in your Linq query.  For example, Folder and folder.

Comment: I am accessing the property via `Folder` which I not shown above. `        public string Folder
        {
            get { return folder; }
            set 
            { 
                folder = value;
                PropChanged("Folder");
            }
        }'

Comment: The ordering should work fine with the example given. Are you sure that tempFavs is populated in the 2nd example before you do the ordering?

Comment: Ah you are right, in the second example, I made a mistake somewhere by assigning `settings.FavouritesSetting` to an empty value so `tempFavs ` was not populated.